# WCF tracing add a filter

Tags: wcf, trace

I would like to add a filter to my WCF tracing to either filter on an endpoint or on the content of the message.

It is not clear from what I have seen on how to do this. I am trying to do this in the web.config file.

Any ideas welcome.

Thanks
Ian

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below configuration, tracing the WCF activity.

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" propagateActivity="true" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" name="xmlLog" initializeData="myLogs.svclog"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"/>
    </diagnostics>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

You can custom your configuration referring to the below link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/tracing-and-message-logging
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing
After we get the tracing file, We could use `Microsoft Service Trace Viewer` to filter the WCF activity.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/service-trace-viewer-tool-svctraceviewer-exe
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/using-service-trace-viewer-for-viewing-correlated-traces-and-troubleshooting
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.